# Barplot stops functioning when adding a key in ggvis (needed for tooltip)

Tags: r, tooltip, shiny, bar-chart, ggvis

I want to have a tooltip on my bar graph that shows detailed info about a customer when hovered over. The problem is that without a defined key the tooltip does not function and with a defined key the barplot does not function properly anymore. Here is the data I used:

CustomerData:

```
id;CustomerID;CLV;Gender;Channel;Age
1;1;300;male;facebook;24
2;2;2000;female;google ads;34
3;3;500;female;other;43
4;4;1300;male;google ads;34
5;5;100;male;other;46
6;6;400;female;other;32
7;7;600;female;google ads;43
8;8;1000;male;other;46
9;9;200;female;other;75
10;10;1700;male;google ads;35
11;11;1600;female;google ads;23
12;12;800;female;other;54
13;13;400;female;other;34
14;14;700;male;google ads;42
15;15;500;male;facebook;18
16;16;200;male;other;42
17;17;1900;male;google ads;46
18;18;400;female;other;23
19;19;600;male;other;45
20;20;200;female;other;42
21;21;1400;male;facebook;57
22;22;1200;female;facebook;54
```

Ui Code:

```
#this is the ui code


shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("CLV Reporting"),

  sidebarPanel(
    navbarMenu(
               checkboxGroupInput("gender", 'Gender:',
                       c("female" = "female",
                         "male" = "male"))),
    navbarMenu(
               checkboxGroupInput("channel", 'Channel:',
                       c("Facebook" = "facebook",
                         "Google Ads" = "google ads",
                         "Other" = "other"))),
    navbarMenu(
               sliderInput("age", "Age Range:",
                        min = 0, max = 100, value = c(20,50)))


  ),

  mainPanel(

ggvisOutput("barplot"),
         textOutput("mean"),
         textOutput("price")
  )
))
```

Server Code:

```
    #this is the server code

library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)



shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  report <- reactive({

    gender <- input$gender
    channel <- input$channel
    minage <- input$age[1]
    maxage <- input$age[2]

    rep <- CustomerData %>%
      filter(
        Gender %in% gender,
        Channel %in% channel,
        Age >= minage,
        Age <= maxage
      )


  })

  #tooltip input
  Customer_tooltip <- function (x) {
    if (is.null(x)) return(NULL)
    if (is.null(x$id)) return(NULL)

    CustomerData <- isolate(report())
    customer <- CustomerData[CustomerData$id == x$id, ]

    paste0("<b>", "Customer ID: ", customer$CustomerID, "</b><br>",
           "Gender: ", customer$Gender, "</b><br>",
           "Channel: ", customer$Channel, "</b><br>",
           "Age: ", customer$Age, "<br>",
           "CLV: $", format(customer$CLV, big.mark = "'", scientific = FALSE)
    )
  }


  # output


  vis <- reactive({   


  report %>%
    ggvis(x = ~factor(CustomerID), y = ~CLV) %>%
    layer_bars(fillOpacity := 0.5, fillOpacity.hover := 1, key := ~id) %>%
    add_tooltip(Customer_tooltip, "hover") %>%
    add_axis("x", title = "Customer") %>%
    add_axis("y", title = "CLV", title_offset = 60) %>%
    set_options(width = 500, height = 300)

    })

  vis %>% bind_shiny("barplot")

  output$mean <- renderText({   
    m <- report()
    if (nrow(m) != 0) {paste("The mean CLV of the selected customers is: $", round(mean(m$CLV)))}
    else {"There are no customers with these specifications."}
    })

  output$price <- renderText({
    m <- report()
    if (nrow(m) != 0) {paste("We recommend to spend $", round(mean(m$CLV)/12)*nrow(m), " on retaining these customers.")}
    else {""}
  })

})
```

I added the id column because I thought this could solve the problem (using a key which is not used by anything else in the code). Just in case you wondered why there were two variables with the exact same values ;)

(edit) I uploaded the newest version to gisthub: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f04325078f9c0656ab72

packages needed: shiny, ggvis, dplyr and ggplot2